# How do I build a boiler plate for node js using express generator

Tags: node.js, express

I am new to the world of javascript. How do I scaffold out a node boiler plate. I heard express generator is one best option. Can I use it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Express generator is a very good option. But the thing is you should first understand how node works basically. Express generator builds a sample boiler plate for you which most of the code is already written.
To use it, first install express generator globally as follows

```
npm install -g express-generator
```

Then to scaffold out a project do

```
express <YOUR APPNAME>
```

But, What I would suggest is try to build out your own boiler plate so that you get full understanding of how it works.
Let me know if you face any problems.
Enjoy node!